# Exporting the Bazaar log to a printable format?

Tags: bazaar

I have a thesis project that requires a project log to be submitted along with my final paper. As part of that log I'd like to include the Bazaar revision log and all the messages that it contains but I'll need to have them in a printable format.

I was unable to find any export feature in the Bazaar Explorer tool but I hope it's still possible to do somehow. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you call "printable"?

Comment: @maarons - Any common format really (txt, rtf, html, csv...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get log in the text format using command-line: `bzr log > log.txt` or via Bazaar Explorer with running All Commands dialog and select `log` command there and then copy the log from status window. Read the help for [`log`](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.3/en/user-reference/log-help.html) command to find the appropriate options. You may want to use `-n0` option and maybe `--forward` one.

Comment: Super, thank you. I used the All Commands dialog with the "--forward" flag and then copied the output to notepad.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, you can use the [bzr-xmloutput](https://launchpad.net/bzr-xmloutput) plugin to get an xml version and then process that into exactly what you want.